# Why is the zip() function not returning expected results in list using Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping, zip

I have a block of code using Python/Selenium that is supposed to iterate through various items on a webpage and display whether or not the item is available and if it is, show the name and color of the item as well as provide a link to the page. The code works as expected on items that are sold out but when it gets to the first available item python simply returns 'available' and provides the name/url of the last item on the page instead of the expected item. the block of code:

```
shirts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id='container']/article/div/h1/a""")
colors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id='container']/article/div/p/a""")
articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
for article in articles:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(article).perform()
    if article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == "sold out":
        print("sold out")
    elif article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == "":
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(article).perform()
        print("available")
    for shirt, color in zip(shirts, colors):
        shirt_text = shirt.text
        color_text = color.text
    print shirt_text, color_text
    link = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/a').get_attribute('href')
    print(link)
```

here's a snippet of what the above code returns:
(the expected item that should be displayed is the Plaza Sunglasses Magenta)

```
sold out
sold out
available
Supreme®/Hanes® Crew Socks (4 Pack) White
https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories/zf83g0dx4/hijz30rq8
sold out
sold out
sold out
sold out
sold out
sold out
```

and the link to page that I'm scraping:
http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories

Is my script not set up properly or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only printing the last product name because your `shirts` list contains all the product names on the entire page and `shirt_text` is set to the last item in that list.

Instead, move the queries for the name and color into the article loop:

```
for article in articles:
    if article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == 'sold out':
        print('sold out')
    else:
        print('available')
        [...]
        nameLink = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/h1/a')
        colorLink = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/p/a')
        [...]
```

Comment: move the queries into the top article loop for sold out items or the bottom loop?

Comment: You'd extract the name only when the item is available.